# Skip an entry WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = X And corresponding entry = 'Y'

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with the ROW_NUMBER() partitioned over the User:

```
Row|Activity|User
-----------------
1  |A       |Jeff
2  |A       |Jeff
3  |A       |Jeff
1  |A       |Bob
2  |B       |Bob
3  |C       |Bob
1  |A       |Sam
2  |B       |Sam
3  |A       |Sam
4  |D       |Sam
```

I would like to skip, during the row count, the entry 3 for Jeff and Sam because if a User's 3rd Activity is A, I should skip it. I call the to-be-skipped rows 'restricted rows'. Basically, I want this table as a result (Without the comments obviously):

```
Row|Activity|User
-----------------
1  |A       |Jeff
2  |A       |Jeff --3rd activity is A so it gets skipped
1  |A       |Bob
2  |B       |Bob
3  |C       |Bob --3rd activity isn't A so it doesn't get skipped
1  |A       |Sam
2  |B       |Sam --3rd activity is A so it gets skipped
3  |D       |Sam
```

My query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY User) AS Row, Activity, User FROM Table1
WHERE [Filters]
AND User IN(SELECT User IN Table1
            WHERE [Filters] --Same filters as above
            GROUP BY User HAVING COUNT(User) > 1) --Let's call this the 'Minimum 1 Activity Filter'
```

I am going to be perfectly honest, right now, I don't know if the Minimum 1 Activity Filter will cause problems later, aka if Row 2 will also have restrictions. Because of that, I prefer treading on the safe side and imagine that I will have to check the Minimum 1 Activity Filter once all the restricted rows have been taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if a User's 3rd Activity is A, I should skip it

Consider:

```
select 
    row_number() over(partition by user order by id) rn,
    activity,
    user
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partiton by user order id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where not (rn = 3 and activity = 'A')
```

Note that, for this to work, you do need a column that can be used to *sort* the records - I assumed column `id`.